# error:on declaring @synthesize method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have code in my .h file as follows

```
@interface tweetViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource ,UIPickerViewDelegate> {

    NSArray *activities;
    NSArray *feelings;

}
```

and in my .m file i used @synthesize property

```
#import "tweetViewController.h"
@synthesize activites,feelings;
```

but it shows me error message....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put it in an implementation.

Replace the `@synthesize ...` line with this:

```
@implementation tweetViewController
@synthesize activities, feelings;

@end
```

You also need to declare `@property`s for this, and close the `@interface` the correct way:

Replace the following lines:

```
@interface tweetViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource ,UIPickerViewDelegate> {

    NSArray *activities;
    NSArray *feelings;

}
```

With this:

```
@interface tweetViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource , UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *activities;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *feelings;

@end
```

Comment: And you also need to have properties for them in the interface.

Answer (score 3):

Variables declared inside the braces `{}` are called `ivars` or`instance variables`. Actually you should declare properties like this.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *activities;
```

So your code looks like this,

```
@interface tweetViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource ,UIPickerViewDelegate> {

    NSArray *activities; // ivar
    NSArray *feelings;  // ivar
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *activities; // property
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *feelings;  // property
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface tweetViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource ,UIPickerViewDelegate> {

    NSArray *activities;
    NSArray *feelings;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *activities;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *feelings;

@end
```

you should first declare property. Try this code.